# Most Elegant Way to Share Theorem/Lemma/Exercise Numbering Across Multiple Articles

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I am currently editing a series of notes for a course. Each part of notes is a separate Latex article. But I want the theorem, lemma, and exercise numbering to be consistent between articles. For instance, if the last Lemma of Notes1 is Lemma 4, I want the first Lemma of Notes2 to be numbered Lemma 5. Is there an elegant way to do this other than manually editing each document to start at the appropriate value?

Comment: I think you need the [xr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) package. Well, that will give you cross-referencing. To number everything in sync between the documents you will need to work harder. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Another, easier, alternative is to use [subfiles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package.

Comment: Why not put them in one article so it all works out of the box? You can use the `titling` package to make each look like its own thing. And, of course, they can be in separate `.tex` files. Or you could just use a master file for compilation and something like `standalone` so you can leave the files' preambles alone.